# Which prepositional phrase should come first?

Tags: preposition, phrase, word-order

In English, I want to say:

> There is no train to return home after arriving at the airport

Is the following sentence the most direct translation in German?

> Es gibt keine Zugverbindung nach Haus nach der Ankunft am Flughafen
>   zurückzukehren

Or should I change the prepositional phrase to make it more natural?

> Es gibt keine Zugverbindung nach der Ankunft am Flughafen nach Haus
>   zurückzukehren

Or is this grammatically correct or more natural?

> Nach de Ankunft am Flughafen, gibt es keine Zugverbindung nach Haus
>   zurückzukehren

Comment: There is a more central problem with your translation suggestions than the one you are asking about. *to return home* has to be translated either to *zurück nach Hause* or to ***um** nach Hause zurückzukehren.*

Comment: Note that an infinitive construction like *to return home* in English will almost always be turned into an infinitive with *zu* in German.

Comment: Nach der Ankunft auf dem Flugplatz gibt es keinen Anschlußzug nach Hause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert the interfix »zu« into a seperable verb like »zurückkehren« to build »zurück**zu**kehren«, you also need the word »um« in the sentence:

> Ich werde zurückkehren. = I will return.
>   Ich nehme den Zug **um** zurück**zu**kehren. = I take the train **to** return.

After having cleared this, here is the closest translation:

> There is no train to return home after arriving at the airport.
>
> Es gibt keinen Zug um nach der Ankunft am Flughafen nach Hause zurückzukehren.

But remember, that word order in German language is more flexible then in English. So this are also good translations:

> Nach der Ankunft am Flughafen gibt es keinen Zug um zurück nach Hause zu kehren.
>   Um nach der Ankunft am Flughafen nach Hause zurückzukehren gibt es keinen Zug.

You also can replace »Zug« by »Zugverbindung« which doesn't change the meaning dramatically, but »Zugverbindung« is not the exact translation of »train«.

- »Zug« = »train«
- »Zugverbindung« = »connection by train«

Comment: Maybe you should add that while this is a direct translation, it's not a very natural translation. Nobody would actually say "nach Hause zurückzukehren".

Comment: *If you insert the interfix »zu« into a seperable verb like »zurückkehren« to build »zurückzukehren«, you also need the word »um« in the sentence* – Far too general. _Er versprach, bald zurückzukehren_ is fine, and adding an _um_ would make this sentence ungrammatical.